# Gatsby build on Nginx not loading js on build

Tags: ubuntu, digital-ocean, gatsby, static-site

I have a static site made with Gatsby and WP for the backend.I am trying to deploy the website on DigitalOcean to test server speed differences with Netlify. I have the same git deployed on Netlify and it works great. When it comes to deploy it on any Ubuntu like server i have always the same problem.
Here is what I have done:

Made an Ubuntu Droplet
Installed nginx
Installed npm
Intalled node
Cloned the repo in /var/www
Made a production build with "gatsby build" after npm install The build give me success. if I point to: http://46.101.101.149/filipporivolta.it-gatsby/public/ where the build is living for testing purposes, images and js are not loaded. The same repo built on netlify works great: https://www.filipporivolta.online

I have the same problem on all environments. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you change the server root in your nginx config to `/var/www/html/public`?

Comment: No, but I think it doesn't matter, If I point to /public with my browser I should manage to see the right website.

Comment: But you do see the right website.

Comment: it looks like the site is looking at the root (46.101.101.149) for resources. perhaps you need to add `filipporivolta.it-gatsby` or `filipporivolta.it-gatsby/public` as your [pathPrefix](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/)

Comment: Yes I see the right website but resources like js and image are not loaded, it should looks like filipporivolta.online